# Ajax call for second submit button of a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, form-submit

I'm using spring boot and thymeleaf.
Managing to call a spring controller method on click of first submit button.
I'm trying for a Ajax call on hit of second submit button , how can I achieve it?

Ajax call for the second submit button

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#download").click(function() {
    var checked = [];
    $('.checkbox:checked').each(function() {
      checked.push($(this).val());
    });

    console.log(checked);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "selectedsalesDownload",
      data: {
        name: checked
      },
      success: function(msg) {
        console.log(mgs);
        alert(msg);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<form name="salesList" th:action="@{/selectedsales}" th:object="${sales}" method="post">
  <div class="container">
    <hr>
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th>SELECT</th>
          <th>Mandy Name</th>
          <th>GSTIN</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr id="salesDataTable" th:each="tempSales:${sales}">
          <td>
            <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" th:name="selected" th:value="${tempSales.ID}" />
          </td>
          <td th:text="${tempSales.mandyName}"></td>
          <td th:text="${tempSales.gstin}"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="SELECT" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3" />
      <input id="download" type="submit" value="DOWNLOAD" name="download" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Controller Method for first submit button

```java
@PostMapping("/selectedsales")
public String selectedSales(
        @RequestParam(value = "selected", required = false) List<Integer> selectedList,
        Model model
) {
    //...
}
```

Controller Method for second submit button

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/selectedsalesDownload")
@ResponseBody
public String toDownload(@RequestParam("name") List<Integer> list) {
    return "msg";
}
```

I'm not able to get into "toDownload" method in the controller on click of second submit button instead I'm getting into first submit button controller method "selectedSales".

And also I need to send the checked box value which is stored in the javascript array variable "checked" to spring controller method "toDownload".

Need Solution.

Comment: Make your _download_ button `type="button"` so it doesn't submit the form when clicked

Comment: changed the type to button , now I'm getting "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()" in the console. What can be done?

Comment: What do the logs from your Spring app say?

Comment: nothing!! No errors in eclipse console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things here...

1. You aren't preventing the second submit button from submitting the form normally. Either use a *button* type...

   ```html
   <input id="download" type="button" ... />
   ```

   or make sure you prevent the default event action

   ```js
   $("#download").on("click", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault()
     // and so on
   })
   ```
2. `@RequestParam` list parameters should be sent with the following format for the greatest compatibility

   ```
   name=1&name=2&name=3...
   ```

   Unfortunately, the default for jQuery is

   ```
   name[]=1&name[]=2&name[]=3...
   ```

   probably for compatibility with PHP. You can change this though via the `traditional` option

   ```js
   $.ajax({
     method: "POST",
     url: "selectedsalesDownload",
     data: {
       name: checked
     },
     traditional: true, //  note the value here
     success: function(msg) {
       console.log(mgs);
       alert(msg);
     }
   });
   ```

   See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ and more specifically https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Comment: traditional: true, //  note the value here , this change made it work. What does it mean??

Comment: @Shreyas did you read the link I added at the bottom of my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need two submit buttons? Which one actually completes the form?

Adding the following code to your JS would immediately solve the issue, but ultimately you really should change one of those submit inputs to `type="button"` as well. This will prevent the default functionality of the form element and you can then override it with your own code:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    // Your other code to execute on form submission
});
```

Comment: On changing it to button I'm getting "POST http://localhost:8080/selectedsalesDownload 400" in browser console. Still not able to get into "toDownload" method in spring controller.

Comment: Hmm is it because you declare `@RequestParam("name") List<Integer> list` as the parameter? Shouldn't it just be a boolean rather than an integer List?